# Visual Studio Dynamic Library: OpenGL don't create window

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, dll, interface

I have a problem. I decided to make an interface so that I can override functions for OpenGL, DirectX and so on ..
The problem is that opengl window is not being created in my dynamic project. But when I create a window without a dynamic library, then the window is created without problems.
Why, when I try to create a window through a dynamic library, it is not created?

Below I will briefly provide the project structure

My visual studio solution consists of two projects: GLRenderSystem and MeshEditor
GLRenderSystem - dynamic library. Here I have two classes declared, GLRenderSystem.h, GLWindow.h which will inherit from the IRenderSystem and IWindow interfaces:

GLWindow.h:

```
 #pragma once
#ifndef _GL_WINDOW_
#define _GL_WINDOW_

#include "../Interfaces/IWindow.h"
#include <glfw\glfw3.h>

class GLWindow : public IWindow
{
public:  
    GLWindow(const std::string& title, uint32_t width, uint32_t height);// Window is not creating.
    ~GLWindow();
    uint32_t getWidth() const;
    uint32_t getHeight() const;

    GLFWwindow* getGLFWHandle() const;
private:
    GLFWwindow* glfwHandle;
};
#endif
```

GLWindow.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "GLWindow.h"
#include<iostream>

GLWindow::GLWindow(const std::string & title, uint32_t width, uint32_t height)
{
    glfwHandle = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title.data(), nullptr, nullptr); // ALWAYS NULL POINTER RETURNS
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(glfwHandle);

    static bool initGLAD = false;
    if (!initGLAD)
    {
        initGLAD = true;
        gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress);
    }
    ......
```

Also Exports.h and Exports.cpp with functions neede to create IRenderSystem and IWindow in the main MeshEditor

Exports.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

#ifdef OGL_RENDER_SYSTEM_EXPORT
#define OGL_RENDER_SYSTEM_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define OGL_RENDER_SYSTEM_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class IRenderSystem;
class IWindow;

extern "C" OGL_RENDER_SYSTEM_API IRenderSystem* createRenderSystem();
extern "C" OGL_RENDER_SYSTEM_API IWindow* createWindow(const std::string& title, uint32_t width, uint32_t height);
...
```

Exports.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Exports.h"

#include "GLWindow.h"
#include "GLRenderSystem.h"
#include<iostream>

OGL_RENDER_SYSTEM_API IRenderSystem * createRenderSystem()
{
    return new GLRenderSystem;
}

OGL_RENDER_SYSTEM_API IWindow * createWindow(const std::string & title, uint32_t width, uint32_t height)
{   
    return new GLWindow(title, width, height);   
}
...
```

And finally, the MeshEditor project, where from main.cpp I try to create a window using a dynamic library

```
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/transform.hpp>

#include "../Interfaces/IWindow.h"
#include "../Interfaces/IRenderSystem.h"

#include "DynamicLibrary.h"
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    DynamicLibrary dll("GLRenderSystem.dll");

    auto createRenderSystem = dll.getSymbol<IRenderSystem* (*)()>("createRenderSystem");
    auto createWindow = dll.getSymbol<IWindow* (*)(const std::string& title, uint32_t width, uint32_t     height)>("createWindow");
    auto waitEvents = dll.getSymbol<void(*)()>("waitEvents");
    auto swapDisplayBuffers = dll.getSymbol<void(*)(IWindow* window)>("swapDisplayBuffers");
    auto windowShouldClose = dll.getSymbol<bool(*)(IWindow* window)>("windowShouldClose");

    IRenderSystem* rs = createRenderSystem();
    IWindow* window = createWindow("myWindow", 640, 480); // ALWAYS NULL POINTER RETURNS
    rs->init();
    rs->setupLight(0, glm::vec3{ 0,5,0 }, glm::vec3{ 1,0,0 }, glm::vec3{ 0,1,0 }, glm::vec3{ 0,0,1 });
    rs->turnLight(0, true);

    while (!windowShouldClose(window))
    {
        rs->setViewport(0, 0, window->getWidth(), window->getHeight());
        rs->clearDisplay(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        renderScene(*rs);
        swapDisplayBuffers(window);
        waitEvents();
    }

    delete window;
    delete rs;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the createWindow function in main.cpp always returns nullptr, that is, window is  not created.

Comment: You didn't export the class itself. But even if you do, it will not work if you load the DLL at runtime using `LoadLibrary()` because all the member functions will not be imported either. You have to use a `.lib`  file and link against that, or you must provide exported functions. Also it's not a good idea to pass `string` (or other containers) across DLL boundaries.